# How to find more than one process pinned to the same core?

Tags: linux, shell

```
$ lsisolcpus
core pid   foreign comm  cmdline
30   27213 2147    Test1 ./Test1
30   27214 2157    Test2 ./Test2
```

I use `lsisolcpus` to find cores used by different processes.

Question> Is there a way that I can automatically detect when more than one process is pinned to the same cpu core? In above example, I would like to see the script complains that there is a conflict because both `Test1` and `Test2` are pinned to the core 30.

Comment: Maybe something along the lines of `lsisolcpus | awk '{print $1}' | sort | uniq -d` ?

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
lsisolcpus | awk 'NR==1 {next} { cpus[$1][$4]="" } END { for ( i in cpus) { cnt=0;for (n in cpus[i]) {cnt++} if (cnt>1) { print "WARNING - conflict on core - "i;for (o in cpus[i]) { print o } } } }'
```

Taking the output of the lsisolcpus command and feeding it into awk. We ignore the first line of the output (NR==1) and then build a 2 dimensional array of the output (cpus) indexed by core and command. We then loop through the array and then if there is more than one entry for each core (cnt>1), we print an error message and the commands tied to that core.